# VBA User Defined Function only Working on one Worksheet in Workbook

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I have the below code that creates an array from a table in excel and then searches that array based on multiple criteria from the inputs.

```
Function output_string(id As Long, dt As Date, descr As String)

'set variables
Dim myarray As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim col_count As Integer
Dim row_count As Long
Dim source_range As Range

'set worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Data Store")

dt = DateValue(app_dt)

'set up column and row counts for populated range
col_count = ws.Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column
row_count = ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

'set range for populated cell space
Set source_range = ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(row_count, col_count))

'create the dimensions of the array that will store the table
ReDim myarray(1 To source_range.Rows.Count, 1 To source_range.Columns.Count)

'load data from excel table into array
myarray = source_range.Value


'get row with matching criteria
For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
    If myarray(i, 1) = id And dt >= myarray(i, 2) And dt <= myarray(i, 4) _
       And descr = myarray(i, 5) Then
       output_string = myarray(i, 3)
       Exit For
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

The function gives the correct output.  The problem is that the function only works on the `Data Store` worksheet.  All the other worksheets return the `#VALUE!` error when I put in the exact same input.  The arguments to the function can be cell references from other worksheets without erroring out.

Also, every once and a while (seemingly at random) the working function on the `Data Source` tab will convert from a correct value to `#VALUE!` as well.

I have the function in a regular module in the same workbook that I'm using.  The module also has a sub program in it.

I'm really stumped on this one.  Has anyone seen this before/do you know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line, as you mentioned in the comment's here, is causing the issue:

```
'set range for populated cell space
Set source_range = ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(row_count, col_count))
```

The problem is that `Cells(2,1)` and `Cells(row_count, col_count)` are range objects that have not been properly qualified with their worksheet. I know it seems counterintuitive since you are already saying `ws.range` here, but these `range` objects must also be qualified with `ws`:

```
'set range for populated cell space
 Set source_range = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(row_count, col_count))
```

Without that qualification it will use the `Application.Activesheet` as the default, which is probably the sheet that is acting as the `Application.Caller.Parent` in this UDF context that you are in. So it's trying to make a range in `ws` made up of beginning and ending cells in your `activesheet` which is nonsense.

Comment: That's very interesting and thank you for sharing.  My question may have not been clear on this point: I need the array to be generated from the `Data Source` sheet no matter what sheet the UDF is used in.  If I understand correctly, this line  `Set ws = Application.Caller.Parent` would generate the array in the same sheet that the function is in.  Do you know of any way to have the array generated on the `Data Source` sheet everytime and still have the function work in other sheets?  Maybe I just have to make the array global and have the function call on it?

Comment: Gotcha. That makes more sense then. Since it's REALLY difficult to say why you might be getting a #value out of this thing, perhaps set some breakpoints in your code and recalculate. Check out the Locals pane and see that the values being assigned to your variable are matching with expectations. There's no issue with referencing other sheets in a UDF.

Comment: It looks like it is crashing on this line `Set source_range = ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(row_count, col_count))` when used in another worksheet, but not when used in the `ws` worksheet.  Do you have any idea why that would be?  The code is so simple I don't know where I could've gone wrong.

Comment: That's it! Sorry I missed that. I have updated my answer.

Comment: YES!  Works like a charm. Thank you very much, you saved me!  Funny how something so small can cause such a headache.  Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad that did the trick! I've lost some hair over that one too.